# Is there a way to resolve it for common js: "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I'm getting this error only when start my unit test with Jest. But app works fine itself. No errors. There is no clear solution in other Stackoverflow answers. It's just js not ts code.
babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  retainLines: true,
  plugins: [
    'react-hot-loader/babel',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
    'babel-plugin-styled-components',
  ],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-flow'],
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-flow'],
    },
    development: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-flow'],
    },
  },
};
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.jsx$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
  },
  globals: {
    NODE_ENV: 'development',
  },
  setupFiles: ['@babel/polyfill', './jest.setup.js'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src', 'src/client', 'src/client/components'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^uuid$': require.resolve('uuid'),
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '!node_modules/(?!@src/*.)',
  ],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/dist/**',
    '!**/coverage/**',
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['text-summary', 'lcov', 'cobertura'],
  reporters: ['default', 'jest-junit'],
  notify: true,
};
```

package.json script:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=development jest src --coverage -u --detectOpenHandles --verbose=true --forceExit",
```

Comment: try to remove 'moduleDirectories' & 'transformIgnorePatterns' from your jest.config.js

Comment: it's hard go give definitive answer as the question isn't really reproducible. Maybe you can share some more retails like the entire output with the error, or the library that has the `import` statement

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rest of the app is written with module (`import`) syntax. If that is the case, you could choose to force using that by adding `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file.

Then if you want the files above to still work, you can change the extensions to `.cjs`, or rewrite them with module syntax.

Comment: forcing type set to module breaks every other components. So wondering why jest works with one component but does not with another